# Profiling Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, profiling

**The case**

I committed an NHibernate transaction that inserts a few rows on some tables, 20 rows on 4 tables, a titpical hierachical structure. 
All is fine in development, but in production the time is expensive.
In dev is instant, in production it takes 3-4 seconds.
Profiling I saw that the single statements durations are 0 but they are delayed in time.

So I prepared a test.

I started profiling a transaction on sql server.
I set up a simple case, 10 inserts on a simple table with an int column.
I send them with a console application on a pc in the same lan (but i also tested it on the same sql server machine).

The operations have duration of 0, and are scheduled in the same time span.

```
EventClass: RPC:Completed   
TextData: exec sp_executesql N'insert into test @p0;',N'@p0 int',@p0=1 
StartTime: 2017-11-09 17:09:29.800  
End Time: 2017-11-09 17:09:29.800
Duration: 0

EventClass: RPC:Completed   
TextData: exec sp_executesql N'insert into test @p0;',N'@p0 int',@p0=2
StartTime: 2017-11-09 17:09:29.800  
End Time: 2017-11-09 17:09:29.800
Duration: 0
```

When i test it on production the duration is still of 0 seconds but i can see a delay of 100-300 ms each statement:

```
EventClass: RPC:Completed   
TextData: exec sp_executesql N'insert into test @p0;',N'@p0 int',@p0=1 
StartTime: 2017-11-09 17:09:29.800  
End Time: 2017-11-09 17:09:29.800
Duration: 0

EventClass: RPC:Completed   
TextData: exec sp_executesql N'insert into test @p0;',N'@p0 int',@p0=2
StartTime: 2017-11-09 17:09:29.930  
End Time: 2017-11-09 17:09:29.930
Duration: 0
```

[image]

I think this is related to the limit of processes the server can evade in this time.

What type of considerations can I do?

- is it related to the network latency?

I tested it also on the sql server machine but invain

- is it related to the chatty operations?

They are all single statements in a transactions (i'm simulating a simple case, in real i'm using nhibernate, that works in the same way). So put all in a procedure can be in this case a possible solution but it is a symptom to manage in all the application.

- is it related to the stress on the server?

I tried some profiling queries but i cannot see waits, task waits or cpu at 100%, it seems stable.

Thanks for the support.

Comment: can you see if you can run all the statements in a single transaction and check for the stats

Comment: I added a screen of the profiler. 
Yes the are under the same transaction, but different procedure calls (1 .net command each operation).
Do you mean the client statistics? I tried but i can't find something useful.